# PHP if/else always going to else, even when IF is succesful

Tags: php, if-statement

I have this `foreach`, which matches a postal code `$searchvalue` to an array of districts. The `if` statement does its job and executes succesfully, if there is no `else`.

However, when I uncomment the `else`, then the `else` is always executed.

Why is this the case?

```
foreach ($districts['district'] as $district) {
    if (in_array($searchvalue, $district['postalcodes'])) { //Search for known Postal Code
        $emails[] = $district['email'];

        //Assign new mail address
        $notification['to'] = implode("",$emails);

        //Continue sending email
        return $notification; //this succeeds without the else below. When the Else is uncommented, this is not executed.
    } 
    else {
        //No known postal code found, fallback
        echo "no valid postal code found, fallback";
        $notification['to'] = $defaultaddress;
        return $notification;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your data set, we can't tell if the if statement is true.

Comment: your for loop repeated many times thats why its gone else part

Comment: What are the values of `$searchvalue, $district['postalcodes']` ? can you do a dump before the if ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `foreach` is going to be stepping through multiple records, so some are going to match and some aren't. Having `else` `return` something will cease execution of the `foreach` so the first non-matching record will stop the loop without evaluating all the rest of the entries.

You appear to want it to `return $notification;` if there's a match *anywhere* in the array, so move the `else` logic *outside* of the `foreach`:

```
foreach ($districts['district'] as $district) {
    if (in_array($searchvalue, $district['postalcodes'])) { //Search for known Postal Code
        $emails[] = $district['email'];

        //Assign new mail address
        $notification['to'] = implode("",$emails);

        //Continue sending email
        return $notification; //this succeeds without the else below. When the Else is uncommented, this is not executed.
    }
}

//No known postal code found, fallback
echo "no valid postal code found, fallback";
$notification['to'] = $defaultaddress;
return $notification;
```

(Side note: You may want to consider what should happen if **multiple** records match. Right now, only the first matching one would receive an email - the rest will be ignored. A `return` *may* not be the ideal action here, depending on your goals and the data.)

Comment: keypoint: move the "unknown-code" behind the foreach, not in the else-case. (else it will return after first unknown match)

Comment: Thx guys! Can't believe this was so simple... It works now :) @ceejayoz, there will always be a single match, so the code is correct now for the current use case. Thanks!